# tableview data not showing up swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Trying to have list of states show up in tableView, but when I run it nothing shows up in the tableView. Everything thing else seems to be working.

```
import UIKit

class licenseViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var items: [String] = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona" , "Arkansas","California", "Colorado" , "Connecticut","Delaware","Florida","Georgia" ,"Hawaii","Idaho","Illinois","Indiana","Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky","Louisiana","Maine","Maryland","Massachusetts","Michigan","Minnesotea","Mississippi","Missouri","Montana","Nebraska","Nevada","New Hampshire","New Jersey","New Mexico","New York","North Carolina","North Dakota","Ohio","Oklahoma","Oregon","Pennsylvani","Rhode Island","South Carolina","South Dakota","Tennessee","Texas","Utah","Vermont","Virginia","Washington","West Virginia","Wisconsin","Wyoming"]

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath:  IndexPath) {
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect to see any data when you specifically told the table view that there are 0 rows?

Comment: Also, by convention classes start with a Capital letter.

Comment: And please spend time looking for a tutorial on using UITableView in Swift. You have two of each of several data source methods. One set is using the Swift 3+ API and the other is using old, out-of-date APIs.

Answer (score 0):

First you return 0 in `numberOfRowsInSection` so no data will be shown, you must return count of the array you want to show and you have another one.

Second you have 2 cellForRow methods, one is deprecated and I left the other that works here below, so remove all your methods in the class and replace all with this:

```
import UIKit

class licenseViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

   @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

   var items: [String] = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona" , "Arkansas","California", "Colorado" , "Connecticut","Delaware","Florida","Georgia" ,"Hawaii","Idaho","Illinois","Indiana","Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky","Louisiana","Maine","Maryland","Massachusetts","Michigan","Minnesotea","Mississippi","Missouri","Montana","Nebraska","Nevada","New Hampshire","New Jersey","New Mexico","New York","North Carolina","North Dakota","Ohio","Oklahoma","Oregon","Pennsylvani","Rhode Island","South Carolina","South Dakota","Tennessee","Texas","Utah","Vermont","Virginia","Washington","West Virginia","Wisconsin","Wyoming"]

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return items.count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     var cell:UITableViewCell =   self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") 

     cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

     return cell
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath:  IndexPath) {
  }

  override func viewDidLoad()
  {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
  }

}
```

Comment: It's pointless to force-cast `dequeueReusableCell` to `UITableViewCell` since that it was it will return.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this

```
import UIKit

class licenseViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var items: [String] = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona" , "Arkansas","California", "Colorado" , "Connecticut","Delaware","Florida","Georgia" ,"Hawaii","Idaho","Illinois","Indiana","Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky","Louisiana","Maine","Maryland","Massachusetts","Michigan","Minnesotea","Mississippi","Missouri","Montana","Nebraska","Nevada","New Hampshire","New Jersey","New Mexico","New York","North Carolina","North Dakota","Ohio","Oklahoma","Oregon","Pennsylvani","Rhode Island","South Carolina","South Dakota","Tennessee","Texas","Utah","Vermont","Virginia","Washington","West Virginia","Wisconsin","Wyoming"]

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self

        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count // return the total items in the items array
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell =  self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
        return cell
   }
```

add this as well

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have two `numberOfRowsInSection` methods in your answer?

Comment: you haven't set delegate and datasource for tableview, check updated answer now

Comment: @rmaddy rectified. Thanks

Comment: You have the wrong signature for the `cellForRowAt` method too.

Comment: @rmaddy had copied the code from question. Changed that as well.